# Proportionally resize iframe to fit in a DIV using jQuery

Tags: jquery, scale, aspect-ratio

I have an iframe of a video inside a div, like so:

```
<div class="media">
    <iframe>
</div>
```

I set the DIV's size dynamically on window resize.

I want to scale the iframe to fit inside the div, **while maintaining it's aspect ratio**. Most of the code out there deals with scaling images, which is easier.

This is what I have so far, but it doesn't work:

```
jQuery.fn.fitToParent = function()
{
    this.each(function()
    {
        var width  = jQuery(this).width();
        var height = jQuery(this).height();
        var parentWidth  = jQuery(this).parent().width();
        var parentHeight = jQuery(this).parent().height();

        if(width < parentWidth)
        {
            newWidth  = parentWidth;
            newHeight = newWidth/width*height;
        }
        else
        {
            newHeight = parentHeight;
            newWidth  = newHeight/height*width;
        }

        jQuery(this).css({
            'height'     :newHeight,
            'width'      :newWidth'
        });
    });
};
```

Basically, I'm looking to replicate the sizing that "background-size: contain" does for images in CSS, but for an iframe in a DIV.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have really improved on the answer from @TrueBlueAussie over time, and thought I'd post a more sophisticated answer here for future reference.

**Made it a plugin on GitHub here: https://github.com/drewbaker/fitToParent**

Here is the jQuery plugin:

```
jQuery.fn.fitToParent = function (options) {

    this.each(function () {

        // Cache the resize element
        var $el = jQuery(this);

        // Get size parent (box to fit element in)
        var $box;
        if( $el.closest('.size-parent').length ) {
            $box = $el.closest('.size-parent');
        } else {
            $box = $el.parent();
        }

        // These are the defaults.
        var settings = jQuery.extend({  
                height_offset: 0,
                width_offset: 0,
                box_height: $box.height(),
                box_width: $box.width(),
        }, options );

        // Setup box and element widths
        var width = $el.width();
        var height = $el.height();
        var parentWidth = settings.box_width - settings.width_offset;
        var parentHeight = settings.box_height - settings.height_offset;

        // Maintin aspect ratio
        var aspect = width / height;
        var parentAspect = parentWidth / parentHeight;

        // Resize to fit box
        if (aspect > parentAspect) {
            newWidth = parentWidth;
            newHeight = (newWidth / aspect);
        } else {
            newHeight = parentHeight;
            newWidth = newHeight * aspect;
        }

        // Set new size of element
        $el.width(newWidth);
        $el.height(newHeight); 

    });
};
```

So, assuming you have HTML of this:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <iframe width="720" height="405" src="//player.vimeo.com/video/19223989"></iframe>
</div>
```

The most basic way to call the plugin is like this:

```
jQuery('#wrapper iframe').fitToParent();
```

But I'll often set #wrapper to be close to window height and width, like this:

```
// Get window height and width
var winHeight = jQuery(window).height();
var winWidth = jQuery(window).width();

// Set wrapper height/width to that of window
jQuery('#wrapper').height(winHeight).width(winWidth);

// Size Iframe
jQuery('#wrapper iframe').fitToParent({
    height_offset: 100, // Put some space around the video
    width_offset: 100, // Put some space around the video
});
```

You can also feed in a custom box size to fit the element in, like this:

```
// Get window height and width
var winHeight = jQuery(window).height();
var winWidth = jQuery(window).width();

// Size element
jQuery('#wrapper iframe').fitToParent({
    height_offset: 100, // Put some space around the video
    width_offset: 100, // Put some space around the video
    box_height: winHeight, // Force use of this box size
    box_width: winWidth // Force use of this box size
});
```

I've also added the ability to set a CSS class of "size-parent" to a parent element, and it will then use that parent element for the box size. A full example of that:

```
// HTML like this
<div id="wrapper" class="size-parent">
    <div class="media">
        <iframe width="720" height="405" src="//player.vimeo.com/video/19223989"></iframe>
    </div>
</div>

// jQuery like this
jQuery('.media iframe').fitToParent();
```

If you don't set a .size-parent, it will fallback to the element parent. If you set the box_height/box_width parameter, then those override everything obviously.

Now, to show how powerful this can be, try this for a vertically centered, horizontal centered aspect ratio correct iFrame!

```
// CSS like this
#wrapper {
    text-align: center;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
#wrapper iframe {
    display: inline-block;
}

// HTML like this
<div id="wrapper" class="size-wrapper">
    <iframe width="720" height="405" src="//player.vimeo.com/video/19223989"></iframe>
</div>

// jQuery like this
// Get window height and width
var winHeight = jQuery(window).height();
var winWidth = jQuery(window).width();

// Size wrapper
jQuery('#wrapper').height( winHeight ).width( winWidth );

// Size element
jQuery('#wrapper iframe').fitToParent({
    height_offset: 200, // Put some space around the video
    width_offset: 200, // Put some space around the video
});

// Fit iFrame to wrapper
jQuery('#wrapper iframe').fitToParent();
```

In real life, I wrap the jQuery in a function, and then call that function on window resize for true responsive iFrames!

Answer (score 7):

Three issues noted:

1. You have an error (trailing quote) in your example:

   `:newWidth'`
2. You need to set the iframe actual height and width attributes and not the style. Styling an iframe size has no effect:

   ```
   $(this).width(newWidth);
   $(this).height(newHeight);
   ```
3. the calculation for aspect ratio was wrong (needs to compare ratios to see which way they overlap). Without this not all overlap cases are catered for.

   ```
   var aspect = width/height;
   var parentAspect = parentWidth/parentHeight;
   if (aspect > parentAspect)
   {
       newWidth  = parentWidth;
       newHeight = newWidth / aspect;
   }
   else
   {
       newHeight = parentHeight;
       newWidth  = newHeight * aspect;
   }
   ```

I also cleaned up the code a little to speed up element access. Each call to jQuery(this) costs cycles.

### JSFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/ZJDkF/8/

### Updates:

The jsfiddle now has examples of the 4 different scenarios of overlap and each retains the proportions of the iframe. I also added the window resize you mentioned and made the first div resize dynamically with it to demonstrate.

Comment: This is amazing, very well done. I'll award the bounty as soon as it lets me.

Comment: Safari would loose ratio on resize, due to rounding errors adding up. So I saved the aspect ratio on display, and they used that ratio for all future sizing: http://jsfiddle.net/ZJDkF/9/

Answer (score 0):

here:

http://jsfiddle.net/fFTS8/

```
  <div id="test" style="width:300px;height:200px;background:red;"></div>
  <script src="js/vendor/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
     jQuery.fn.fitToParent = function()
     {
        var that = this;

        function rezise() {
           that.each(function()
           {
             var a = $(this).width();
             var b = $(this).height();
             var c = $(this).parent().width();
             var d = $(this).parent().height();

             var ab = a/b;
             var cd = c/b;

             var e, f = 0; // e - newWidth, f - newHeight

             if(ab > cd) {
                e = c;
                f = c*b/a;
             } else {
                e = a*d/b;
                f = d;
             }

             $(this).width(e);
             $(this).height(f);
           });
        }

        $(window).resize(function() {
           rezise();
        });
     };
     $('#test').fitToParent();

  </script>
```

Comment: According to the asker the iframe is meant to resize to the parent div. This one is backwards and resizes the div to the JSFiddle iframe.