# Properly scaling or resizing an image or sprite maintaining its original aspect ratio

Tags: java, algorithm, scale, aspect-ratio

I have gone through a lot of answers in this site but unfortunately nothing solves the problem I am about to describe.

I have designed an app with 800x520 in landscape mode. All assets are designed using that predefined window size. I used unit system but I think that's irrelevant here.

Now, I have a sprite/image that is 85x70 in size. I want it to scale but maintaining its original aspect ratio no matter what the window/screen size of the real device is. I have the following so far, which keeps the ratio but doesn't resize properly meaning if the device screen is bigger than my predefined window size by both width and height, it shows the sprite still small. If there's no change in height but only in width or no change in width but only in height, then that's fine. The image should not be scaled on x or y. But this snippet below doesn't do the job.

```
float screenW = Screen.SCREEN_WIDTH; // Predefined width 800
float screenH = Screen.SCREEN_HEIGHT; // Predefined height 520

float deviceW = Gdx.graphics.getWidth(); // Actual device width that can vary
float deviceH = Gdx.graphics.getHeight(); // Actual device height that can vary

float changeX = screenW / deviceW; // Also tried deviceW / screenW 
float changeY = screenH / deviceH; // Also tried deviceH / screenH

// I tried applying the changeX and changeY  above
// in sprite's scale.x and scale.y respectively but no luck
// So I tried the below to get the new size of the sprite 
// with and without applying scale above..
// Tried a lot of ways but no luck

float newWidth = (Sprite.WIDTH * changeX);
float newHeight = (Sprite.HEIGHT * changeY);
```

I do not need any actual code as long as I have a correct algo, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: "doesn't do the job" doesn't give us much to go on. Give us some sample numbers. What is the screen height/width? What is the device height/width? What are the values you're getting, and what are you expecting? The answer Daniel provided should work, so there must be something else that you're not telling us.

Comment: @JimMischel Screen Size (800 width x 520 height = 1.54 aspect ratio). Device size (1024 x 768 = 1.33 aspect ratio). When drawing a circle/square in device, circle/square doesn't keep the ratio and gets scaled up on y, really up applying the solution given by Daniel below. Circle becomes ellipse. I get the scale factor as shown in answer and then apply it to width and height of the circle/square texture by multiplying as stated. Thank you. Sorry if I am still not clear.

Comment: I wrote a jQuery plugin to do just this, it might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18838963/proportionally-scale-iframe-to-fit-in-a-div-using-jquery

Answer (score 2):

The calculation for your `changeX` and `changeY` seems backwards. If the new device has a width of 1600 for example, you would want to scale by a factor of 2. Your `changeX` would be 1/2.

Try something like:

```
float changeX = deviceW / screenW;
float changeY = deviceH / screenH;
```

once you have calculated these you will need to scale by the lesser of the 2 to preserve the aspect ratio.

```
float scale = Math.min(changeX, changeY);
```

Then you can calculate the new value by multiplying the original sprite values by the `scale`

Comment: That doesn't keep aspect ratio.

Comment: Sorry but I tried it and many other solutions from this site but didn't work. Just tried again to be sure but no luck.

Comment: Daniel Jacobson's method is correct. WebApp's problem must be somewhere else.

Comment: @A.I.Breveleri Sorry but it doesn't work and I do not why. I am not new to this. I wanted the finished app to be ported to different tablets so I tried at least for the main character in app should not get scaled badly.