# jQuery auto fit element to its parent (like extjs)

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui

I am working with kendoui, and it is a nightmare to take on element and automatically expand it to fit to its parent.
Is there any plugin for kendoui / jquery to automatically take any element (grid/panel/div) and fit to its parent?

it also need to support parent size change.

```
$("#kendoGrid").fitToParent();
```

**Edit**
Then doing fitToParent, the child div (#kendoGrid) will be 100% width and height of its parent.

Comment: define `fit to parent` It can mean many things. Please provide example

Comment: don't understand why you can't use css...please provide a demo that replicates problem

Comment: Check out my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18838963/proportionally-scale-iframe-to-fit-in-a-div-using-jquery

Answer (score 0):

The grid widget is a bit frustrating to size its height because it puts a `height` CSS style on the element, and you can only specify pixel sizes for that height.

However, you can work around it with a CSS `!important` indicator (which I hate, but what can you do?)

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="grid"></div>
</div>

#wrapper {
    height: 200px;
}
#grid {
    height: 100% !important;
}
```