# Auto-scale contents based on width and height of an <iframe>

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe, aspect-ratio

In [TrueBlueAussie's Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18893921/5025435), an iframe becomes proportionally scaled based on the DIVs width and height. Here's his modified version that I prefer: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5cp1repe/2/)

So my question is, how could I make the contents inside an iframe (after being adjusted using the solution) be automatically and proportionally scaled based off the iframes width and height? When I mean contents, I mean everything inside of it such as images, texts, etc.

After researching, I stumbled upon an attribute that may solve my problem, but after using it with the solution, it had no effect.

Style/CSS Attribute(s):

```
-ms-zoom: 0.75;
-moz-transform: scale(0.75);
-moz-transform-origin: 0 0;
-o-transform: scale(0.75);
-o-transform-origin: 0 0;
-webkit-transform: scale(0.75);
-webkit-transform-origin: 0 0;
```

It seems to me that the effect only takes action when the width and height are left alone. I'm trying to achieve the zoom effect used in the attribute so I don't dynamically interfere with the contents inside.

Do I have to use JavaScript to achieve this? I've been stuck on this problem for about a week and can't seem to find a solution.

**I do understand the [Same-origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy) when it comes to using external sites within the iframe. I'm NOT interested in loading content from external sources.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One very simple solution would be to set your measure to percentages. If you can't work this way, I think `transform` is your best solution. Your `resize` function already does a part of the calculations, what you need to add is a `variable` to get the initial `width` of your `iframe`, then instead of resizing by setting a new `width` and `height`, you use the `newWidth` variable to set a scale factor and you use it in your `tranform css`. Like this:

Set the initial width variable just after the `iframe` is added  to the DOM:

```
    var iframe = document.getElementById('frame'),
    iframedoc = iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow.document;
    iframedoc.body.innerHTML = source, iframeinitialwidth = $('iframe').width();
```

On resize, you use newWidth to calculate the scale you should use and you resize with transform (I've made it with -webkit only but it should work on navigator supporting transform):

```
    ...
    //$iframe.width(newWidth);
    //$iframe.height(newHeight);
    });
    var scaleFactor = newWidth/iframeinitialwidth
    $('iframe').css({'-webkit-transform': 'scale('+scaleFactor+')', '-webkit-transform-origin': '0 0'})
   ...
```

http://jsfiddle.net/368sjapg/2/